# lz4 decompression giving running out of memory

Tags: go, compression, lz4

I am using the library `github.com/bkaradzic/go-lz4` for lz4 decompression. In lz4 decode command, I am getting running out of memory. Due to which, my process is getting killed. Is there any other way to lz4 decompress?

Code:

```
        decompressed := make([]byte, 0)
        decompressed, decErr = lz4.Decode(decompressed, toDecompress)
```

Comment: have you checked https://github.com/pierrec/lz4 ?

Comment: Yes, it works for me.

Comment: So, I am facing new issue. Size of byte array is too big which I need to decompress and it ultimately leads to OOM. So, is there a way that I can decompress large size byte array.

Comment: what have you done ?